# How to create a dialogue box with buttons in simulink and trigger a subsystem based on user selection

Tags: matlab, function, dialog, simulink, subsystem

I want to run a simulink model based on the user selection.

lets say i have to run a equation A = B+C+D+E, where B,C,D,E are also equations. I want to ask user if he has values of B,C,D,E or if he has the values of unknowns of the those equations.
Based on his selection I should find A directly or I should find B,C,D,E first and then find A.

How do i make dialogue box with buttons asking user's input which triggers  subsystem/function based on his selection.

Comment: You are aware that Simulink evaluates expressions you enter into a mask parameter? You can type in something like `1+3*f(7)` and it is evaluated. Not sure what you need to implement.

Comment: @Daniel    I exactly dunno how to use it .  I want to execute few equations , the values of unknowns in those equations are to be asked for users input

Comment: @Daniel can I get the dialogue box pop out when I run the model

Answer (score 0):

Creating a subsystem and masking it works 
If clicked on the subsystem the dialogue box pops up and takes inputs from user as defined.
But dunno if the dialogue box pops when I run the model without clicking on the mask